# Can a planet orbit two stars (or more) in a "non-elliptical" orbit?

Tags: astrophysics

[image: Case 1 and case 2]

(Sorry if my English is weird or my formatting. I'm not used to Stack.)

Anyway, I'm not sure how to summarize the two cases in my mind without the images, but case one is a 3-star system and a planet orbiting two of them at a time (inner orbit) in a corkscrew way, bouncing one from the other. Case two would be a more traditional orbit, with a less traditional "eight" one of the planet being constantly transferred away from one body to another.

Would any of these systems be possible or better, stable?  Would there be any habitable zone in either case?. I apologize for my lack of knowledge in the topic and how broad and hard to answer it may be, but thanks in advance

Comment: One place to start would be the Wikipedia article "Habitability of binary star systems"  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habitability_of_binary_star_systems - There are two types of orbits in binary star systems, S-type where planets orbit one of the stars and P-type where planets orbit both of the stars.  Astronomers have discovered planets in both S-type and P-type orbits.  Planets in either type of orbit could be habitable if orbiting in the habitable zones of their star(s).   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumstellar_habitable_zone#Solar_System_estimates

Answer (score 5):

### Probably not

A similar question, [Can a planet have a figure-8 type of orbit around two separate stars?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2726/can-a-planet-have-a-figure-8-type-of-orbit-around-two-separate-stars), addresses 8-shaped orbits around binary systems, instead of embedded within triple systems. In that question, it was revealed that a non-elliptical orbit can exist between two stars, but it isn't stable. Presumably, life couldn't develop in a two-star "8-orbit" system before the planet was kicked out. This makes your diagram on the right difficult to explain.

A three-star system like the one on the left wouldn't be stable even without planets. The stars will want to orbit the system's barycenter in an ellipse, so the gravitational forces that can distort their elliptical orbits into a figure-8 will probably kick out a star or two given enough time. Plus, it would be difficult for an 8-shaped triple system to form from a spinning disk. It would be even harder for a binary to capture a passing star into a stable orbit. Such a system would not form, and would not be stable in the long term.

### Alternatives

[There are many](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-for-a-planet-to-orbit-three-suns-like-in-Dark-Crystal) stable three-star system configurations in which all orbits are elliptical - and they could conceivably support habitable zones given enough distance between the stars. The closest star to our sun hosts [at least one exoplanet](https://www.space.com/proxima-centuri-candidate-alien-planet-proxima-c.html) in the habitable zone of such a triple-star system.

Comment: Oh, the "infinite" (case 1) was one of the listed "solutions" for the three body problem so I thought it was more stable than case 2. I guess I was wrong. Thank you for the answer! (sadly I cant manage to make a separate paragraph in the editor). So, basically theres no way of orbiting inside a multiple-star-orbit, but rather as if they were one, or planet and sun oribiting them both, not disturbing the involved bodies, right?

Comment: @simon Can you link to a source describing case 1? I could be wrong!

Comment: Yes, sorry for the late answer. The source is: https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~rehmann/ECM/cdrom/3ecm/pdfs/pant3/simo.pdf